# I am trying to use SQL to compare two tables (data analysis)

Tags: sql, mysql

My end goal is to compare two tables, I want to compare 'casual' bike riders to 'member' bike riders. I was thinking to create a new sql table with casual riders and their ride length and same for the members.

```sql
CREATE TABLE member_ride AS
SELECT member_casual, ride_length
FROM `2020.dataset`
WHERE member_casual = 'member'
```

This is giving me an error:

> ```
> Table "member_ride" must be qualified with a dataset (e.g. dataset.table).
> ```

Comment: Maybe you want to use CTE, check this: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-basics/mysql-cte/

Answer (score 0):

Do this

This query create table without any data

```
 SELECT * INTO {schema_name}.newtable 
  FROM {schema_name}.oldtable 
  WHERE 1 = 0;
```

and then you have to insert the data according to your condition

```
 INSERT INTO newtable (States, Company_Website)
SELECT States, company_Website
FROM oldtable
WHERE States='gy';
```